# How to paint from outside unknown class for 2d game engine api

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, 2d, paint

Im trying to make an API for a 2D game engine im currently writting. I have a loader class outside of the package which I would like to have a jpanel or the ability to use one outside of the package and call engine to add the jpanel so I could paint onto the one inside the API so people can simply write without needing the source code.

Here is my Engine class and Loader class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.embah.flatbox.Engine;

public class loader {
    private Engine engine;
    private pane pain = new pane();


    public loader(){
        engine = new Engine("Testing Grounds", 500, 350);
        engine.add(pain);
        engine.revalidate();
        engine.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new loader();
    }
}

class pane extends JPanel{


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Hello worl222d!", 60, 40);
    }
}
```

and my engine class

```
package com.embah.flatbox;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Engine extends JFrame{
    private Render render;

    public Engine(String title, int width, int height){
        render = new Render();
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(title);
        add(render);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addComp(JPanel pane){
        this.add(pane);
    }

    public void repaintEngine(){
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void setTitleFrame(String title){
        setTitle(title);
    }

    public void setSizeFrame(int width, int height){
        this.setSize(width, height);
    }

    public void setVisibleFrame(boolean visible){
        setVisible(visible);
    }

    public String getTitleFrame(){
        return getTitle();
    }

    public int[] getSizes(){
        int[] size = new int[2];
        size[0] = (int) getSize().getWidth();
        size[1] = (int) getSize().getHeight();
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isVisibleFrame(){
        return isVisible();
    }
}
```

Render class is a JPanel that im drawing on until the user draws on it, im just using it for testing right now Ill remove once I find out how to paint from external location.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not entirely clear for me. Do you want to allow the user to add his own *components* into your engine? Or do you want to allow him to do his own *painting operations* into the `Graphics` object that belongs to a JPanel?

Comment: Well the final hope is to allow them to do there own painting operations. Im just using the Panel right now as a graphics holder I guess, I dont quite know how to draw more than one graphics object. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it seems that the actual goal may be achieved with a comparatively simple pattern, which is used frequently in varying forms to achieve this task. Hopefully, I didn't overlook something, but if you just want to give the user of your library the possibility perform custom rendering, you might consider the follwing:

```
class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    private List<Painter> painters = new ArrayList<Painter>();

    void addPainter(Painter painter) {
        painters.add(painter);
    }

    void removePainter(Painter painter) {
        painters.remove(painter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        for (Painter painter : painters) {
            painter.paint(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}


interface Painter {
    void paint(Graphics2D g, int width, int height);
}
```

Then you can create such a `PaintPanel` and put it into your frame, and add `Painter` instances as needed:

```
PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
...
paintPanel.add(new MyCustomPainter());


// Where
class MyCustomPainter implements Painter {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g, int width, int height) {
        // Perform your painting operations here
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(0,0,width,height);
        ....
    }
}
```

Of course, this is just a basic sketch. In order to apply such a concept in a real "Engine", one has to consider many more aspects (e.g: Should it be possible to define an order in which the `painters` should be executed? Should there be different sets of painters for several layers, e.g. foreground/background painters? Details about the state that is encapsulated in the Graphics2D should also be taken into account...). But for the basic purpose of separating the *Component* (that is, the JPanel) from the actual painting operations that are performed (and that are provided by the client, via implementations of the `Painter` interface), maybe this could be a first step.

Comment: Thanks, ill work with this and see how I can make it work for my project! :)